# Decimal contained in another decimal linq

Tags: c#, linq, decimal

I need to search if a decimal (converted to string) is contained in another decimal (also converted to string) in a linq query so if I filter for `09` in `{12309123, 000999, 123459}` i find only the first two "elements" (123**09**123 and 00**09**99).

so far I tried with:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.DecimalProp.ToString().Contains(filtri.DecimalProp.ToString()));
```

but when i try to do `query.toList()` it throws a *System.NotSupportedException* ("Too many characters in character literal"). I looked on the internet but I didn't find anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this linq to SQL,linq to EF, linq to objects, linq to DataTable or what?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write it, it's linq to EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to EF does not support method `ToString` called on an arbitrary object. If you want to do such a convertion in the query, you can use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. This class provides a range of static functions for various sql operations, including a fucntion for converting decimal to string:

```
query = query.Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(x.DecimalProp).Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert(filtri.DecimalProp));
```